# Api Platform pagination custom page_parameter_name

Tags: react-admin, api-platform.com

I have very specific question on which I cannot find any answer and/or solution provided for Api Platform.
By default, the documentation states, that if you want to pass a page parameter for paging action, you must do the following:

```
pagination:
        page_parameter_name: _page
```

However, due to the nature of our frontend we're not able to pass this variable to the request. It is hardcoded to the frontend request and is something like `page[number]=1`.

Is it possible to configure page_parameter_name to receive this variable or we need to transform it somehow in the Api itself?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\ReadListener](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/master/src/EventListener/ReadListener.php)::onKernelRequest gets $context['filters'] from the request through ApiPlatform\Core\Util\RequestParser::parseRequestParams which ultimately uses PHP's parse_str function so the value of 'page[number]' will be in $context$context['filters']['page']['number'].

[ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\Pagination](https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/master/src/DataProvider/Pagination.php)::getPage retrieves the page number from $context['filters'][$parameterName] so whatever the value of [$parameterName] it will at best retrieve the array ['number'=> 1].

Then ::getPage casts that to int, which happens to be 1. But will (at least with PHP7) be 1 for any value under 'number'.

Conclusion: You need to transform it somehow in the Api itself. For example by [decoration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html) of the ApiPlatform\Core\DataProvider\Pagination service (api_platform.pagination).

Answer (score 0):

API_URL?page[number]=2

```
print_r($request->attributes->get('_api_pagination'));
Array(
    [number] => 2
)
```

The value of the "page_parameter_name" parameter should be "number" .

api_platform.yaml

```
collection:
    pagination:
       page_parameter_name: number
```

This may not work in version 3

vendor/api-platform/core/src/JsonApi/EventListener/TransformPaginationParametersListener.php

```
public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
{
  $request = $event->getRequest();
  $pageParameter = $request->query->all()['page'] ?? null;
  ...
  /* @TODO remove the `_api_pagination` attribute in 3.0 */
  $request->attributes->set('_api_pagination', $pageParameter);
}
```